# Date picker consisting of three component pickers

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, ecmascript-6

I made a [UI picker tool](https://github.com/SergioCrisostomo/ComponentPicker), like a "rolling select" to pick vales ([demo here](https://rawgit.com/SergioCrisostomo/ComponentPicker/master/demo.html)).

I made first a independent module with a ES6 Class, basically:

> ```
> class ComponentPicker {
>
>     constructor(target, data){
>         // init stuff
>     }
>
>   deployHTML(target, data) {...}
>     getValue(){...}
>     setValue(val){...}
>     onChange(callback){...}
> }
> ```

Then I added a new layer to it. A Date picker that needs 3 component pickers. I thought about extending the class `ComponentPicker` but I didn't find a way to call 3 times `super`, it would look like

> ```
> class DatePicker extends ComponentPicker{
>   constructor(length) {
>       this.pickers = data.map(component=>{
>             return super(target, component); // <-- weird and wrong
>
>         });
>   }
> ```

So I ended up [doing a "good old" ES5- style of class](https://github.com/SergioCrisostomo/ComponentPicker/blob/1.0.0/src/ComponentPicker.js#L171-L210) like:

```
function DatePicker (target, data) {
    this.wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    this.wrapper.className = 'date-picker';
    target.appendChild(this.wrapper);
    this.pickers = data.map(component=>{
        return new ComponentPicker(target, component);
    });
    return this;
}
DatePicker.prototype.getValue = function(){
    return this.pickers.map(picker=>{
        return picker.getValue();
    });
}
DatePicker.prototype.setValue = function(values){
    // etc
```

and calling it with `new DatePicker();`

It works, but is there another way to reuse/extend the first class into another one that needs to interact with 3 of the original?

Comment: Pretty cool, but on a touch screen its a bit slow / unresponsive.

Comment: @Daedric hmm interesting to know, thank you. Didn't test in touch so much yet, will check! (feedback welcome also!)

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly, you want to create an instance of `DatePicker` which by default has 3 instances of `ComponentPicker` in an array called `pickers`? Then the following should work:

```
class DatePicker extends ComponentPicker{
  constructor(length) {
    this.pickers = data.map(component => new ComponentPicker(target, component));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this Joseph. I thought about that, then I would have to also create new methods like onchange, setvalue, getvalue for this extended class. That means almost re-writing the first component and doing in a "multiple" version. Maybe its better to have the first class in a multiple version from begining and not have the need for a extended class?